# How to access places.bookmarks from Firefox's Add-on SDK (Jetpack)

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I'm making a bookmarks extension for Firefox, I figured out that with Jetpack I can make html UI just like in Google's Chrome.

I need to access Firefox's bookmarks, after looking for a while I notinced that there is no *naively supported* way to access the bookmarks from jetpack's API so I found a module that enables the use of places.

[Jetpack-Modules/places.js](https://github.com/autonome/Jetpack-Modules/blob/master/places.js)

Now, the thing is that I don't know how to make use of this module, so maybe somebody could lead me to the right direction.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did manage to find a file called `places.sqlite` in my Firefox profile directory.  Perhaps sqlite is how you're supposed to access it, absent no naively supported way in Jetpack's API.

Perhaps [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Places_Developer_Guide) is the documentation you're looking for.  I tried the [searching bookmarks](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Places_Developer_Guide#Searching) code (with `var {Cc, Ci, Cu} = require("chrome");` before the code block and `console.log(title+"\t"+uri);` added to the end of the `for` loop) and it seems to work.  `JSON.stringify` doesn't work on the structures due to the circular logic they contain.